# Python List: Use For Loop to Manually Create Elements With Commas Separating Them

Tags: python, list, for-loop, element

I want to create the following python list:

```
[MIN_SPAN_1, MIN_SPAN_2, MIN_SPAN_3]
```

Below is the code I tried:

```
numbers_list = [1, 2, 3]

for i in numbers_list:
    print(('MIN_SPAN' + '_' + str(i)))
```

Below is the resulting output which as you can see is not quite what I want:

```
MIN_SPAN_1
MIN_SPAN_2
MIN_SPAN_3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension is one way like how @Micheal has. Otherwise if you want in your way try this: (Create an empty list and append it)

```
numbers_list = [1, 2, 3]
new_list = []
for i in numbers_list:
    new_list.append(('MIN_SPAN' + '_' + str(i)))
```

output,

```
print(new_list)
>['MIN_SPAN_1', 'MIN_SPAN_2', 'MIN_SPAN_3']
```

Comment: Glad to help! this is just the way you needed as a list. However, list comprehension way is elegant too!

Answer (score 3):

are you trying to do:

```
newlist = ["MIN_SPAN_{}".format(entry) for entry in numbers_list]
```

which would make ["MIN_SPAN_1", "MIN_SPAN_2", "MIN_SPAN_3"]

or are you trying to print the array?

```
newlist = ["MIN_SPAN_{}".format(entry) for entry in numbers_list]
print(newlist)
```

prints out : ["MIN_SPAN_1", "MIN_SPAN_2", "MIN_SPAN_3"]

Comment: `newlist = ["MIN_SPAN_{}".format(entry) for entry in numbers_list]` might be a better idea

Answer (score 0):

> **You can do without loop with just one line**

```
numbers_list = [1, 2, 3]
print(list(map(lambda x:("MIN_SPAN_{}".format(x)),numbers_list)))
```

output:

```
['MIN_SPAN_1', 'MIN_SPAN_2', 'MIN_SPAN_3']
```